# How to trigger back button event used to hide inbuilt keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, back

I want to know the event which is fired when back button is pressed to hide inbuilt keyboard.I want to add a view into layout when back button is pressed to hide keyboard.I am also adding a view when ENTER key of keyboard is pressed but I also want to do the same when back button press to hide keyboard.Whatever I have tried is here.

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
            String string = text.getText().toString();
            if (string.trim().equals("")) {
                image_view.removeView(text);
            } else {

                text.setCursorVisible(false);
                text.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                text.buildDrawingCache();

                Bitmap bmp_text = Bitmap.createBitmap(text
                        .getDrawingCache());
                view = new ZoomRotateImage(ImageEditing.this, bmp_text);
                text.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                image_view.removeView(text);
                image_view.addView(view);
                getUpdatedImage();
            }
            return true;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works fine..Now I just want to implement the same on back button pressed to hide keyboard.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)

Comment: check this other question. Is asking the same, how to know when the user hide the keyboard. There's not direct API way of doing it, but this code works fine.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Get the Event on Device Back button press and hide the Soft Keyboard as below:

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        // hide keyboard here
                  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    } else
        return;

}
```

Comment: It should work @Meghs as i am doing the same for my application. Not getting the event onKeyDown... Have u debugged it? Place the breakpoint at 1st line and check...

Comment: Key Board hide automatic when we press Back button.So no need to code for hiding it.I am using this event to just display Toast.But it doesn't.

Comment: Toast.makeText(this, "Back Key Pressed", 4000).show(); Have u placed like this???